# Derivative of determinant of (parameterized) non-invertible matrix

Tags: matrices, matrix-analysis, matrix-theory

Consider a function $A: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, t \rightarrow A(t)$. I want to compute the derivative of the determinant

$$\frac{d}{dt} \det(A(t)) \; .$$

Suppose $A(t)$ is invertible at some $t = t_0$, then a closed form solution exists (cf. e.g. [The matrix cookbook, p.7](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/teaching/KernelsICS273B/MatrixCookBook.pdf)),

$$\frac{d}{dt} \det(A(t)) \vert_{t=t_0} = \det(A(t_0)) \;\mathrm{tr}\left(A(t_0)^{-1} \frac{d A(t)}{dt}\vert_{t=t_0}\right) \;.$$

Now, what happens if $A(t_0)$ is *not* invertible? Is there still a closed form solution?

Comment: Yes, use the adjugate. Take a look at [Jacobi's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula).

Comment: In other words, just move the determinant factor on the right side into the parentheses.